# Selenium new update opens settings each time I use it for a Chrome Extraction

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, settings, updates

I made a program to extract data from a website using Selenium but I think that with the last update they made I cannot use it properly anymore. Selenium is opening a Windows Setting page for the default applications I'm using.

header code
[image]

[Opening of default applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Pv3.png)

I tried to add those two lines:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-default-browser-check")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-first-run")
```

but didn't work.
I tried to get to the regedit too but unfortunately I didn't find the TriggerReset option so didn't work neither.

Comment: I don't know if it'll help but I've heard that maybe it's coming from a Windows update